# Sum similar subsequent cells and put total in another column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two columns A and B like that

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Up |
| 3 | Up |
| 2 | Up |
| 4 | Down |
| 1 | Up |
| 3 | Up |
| 6 | Down |
| 8 | Down |

And I have the following code that sums the total for each group and put the total at the end of each group. I could do it with loops by this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long, x As Double
    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(r, 2).Value = Cells(r + 1, 2).Value Then
            x = x + Cells(r, 1).Value
        Else
            Cells(r, 3).Value = x + Cells(r, 1).Value
            x = 0
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Is it possible to do such a task using formulas?
I got a solution of doing that by formulas through a helper column, but I am curious if it is possible to do that by one formula?

Comment: What about using `=SUMIF(B:B,"Up",A:A)` this will sum all `Up`? Is that waht you mean? If not can you please show how the desired result would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `=SUMIF(B:B,"Up",A:A)` this will sum all `Up`.

If you want the sum of every group until `Up` changes to `Down` and so on like below

[image]

then put the following formula into C2 and pull it down

```
=IF(B3<>B2,SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

Comment: Amazing. That's exactly the perfect solution. Thanks a lot.